# Python: Deleting mySQL rows that are x many days old

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, raspberry-pi

Im using a raspberry pi with the rasbpian wheezy distribution running headless. I currently have a cronjob that runs a python script to put the current temperature and datetime in a mySQL database 
(table: tempLog, attributes: datetime, temperature float(5,2)).

I want to delete rows that are say 5 days (num days is arbitrary) old and i'm having trouble accomplishing this in python. Here is the code, its not long.

```
import os
import time
import datetime
import glob
import MySQLdb
from time import strftime
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import date

# Variables for MySQL
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root",passwd="password", db="temp_database")
cur = db.cursor()
del_basedate = datetime.datetime.today() - timedelta(1)

# DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 1 DAY)
try:
        cur.execute("DELETE FROM tempLog WHERE datetime.date.day = del_basedate")
        print "Delete successful"

except:
        print "An error occured in: deleteRows.py"

finally:
        cur.close()
        db.close()
```

I had to do sever import from, because it kept throwing errors of objects not existing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about coding context:

```
del_basedate = datetime.datetime.today() - timedelta(1)
   ^^----python variable
```

```
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM tempLog WHERE datetime.date.day = del_basedate")
          text string with the letters "d", "e", "l", "_", etc... --- ^^^
```

Python isn't magical, and will NOT rummage around in a string to see if any of the text in that string LOOKS like a python variable. So you're effectively telling your DB to compare `datetime.date.day` against some unknown/undefined `del_basedate` field.

Try

```
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM tempLog WHERE datetime.date.day = '" +  del_basedate + "'")
                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note the extra quotes within the string. Without them, you'd be comparing against `= 2016-02-18`, which is a math operation, and is parsed/executed by the database as `= 1996`

Comment: it's still throwing the exception, am i using datetime correctly?

Comment: you don't even NEED datetime at all. just do it all in mysql `where yourdatefield < (curdate() - interval 5 day)`

Comment: well it appears to be okay with that syntax, but the delete isn't occuring, could it be because my date field is in the datetime form?

Comment: well, is `datetime.date.day` a valid DB.table.field in your dB?